# Arm cortex-m4 custom os desgin

Tags: arm, kernel, rtos, cortex-m

I am writing a small os for ARM Cortex-M4 core and have some doubts. I decided to place os functionalities through Supervisor Call(SVC) where I keep and maintain all kernel objects and kernel functions.

But, is this a good idea because all kernel code executes and occupies user task stack?

Only thing that comes to my mind is that through supervisor call jump to kernel stack and lock scheduler while executing kernel code. Is this approach a good one?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Cortex-M you have a Process Stack Pointer(PSP) and a Main Stack Pointer(MSP). Interrupts use the Main Stack Pointer and the tasks should use the process stack pointer. Therefore any kernel work done in the SVC uses the MSP so should not interfere with the tasks stacks which use the PSP. When switching tasks you set the PSP to the new stack. I would read the Exception Handling section of the Cortex-M4 Generic User guide. Also I would recommend getting and reading The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex M3/M4 as this has a good section on RTOS's. The Cortex's were design with RTOS's and provide a lot of useful features.

Note: Unless you are doing this as a learning exercise, or just really want to write your own OS, you would be better of using something like FreeRTOS which is very well tested and provides all the features you are ever likely to use.

Comment: Thanks for response, I misunderstood the stacking when exception occurs. I read that part once again and now everything is clear. When exception occurs the stacking is on the running stack, but exception handling happens on MSP stack. By the way, this is just for learning purposes... :)

Comment: Yes, it does take a bit of understanding. The documentation could be better. I would still recommend you take a look at FreeRTOS, it has many portable layers for Cortex which are an excellent way of learning how to do things / reference.